# Strange "oo" Notification Area icon instead of ic_stat_notify in Android

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I am trying to set an alarm notification icon in the Notification
Area doing this:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
            .setCategory(CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setContentTitle("Service")
            .setContentText("Alarm is ON").build();
```

I made my icon in Android Studio using File -> New -> Image Asset -> "Notification Icon" then choosing a pre-defined clip-art.

The strage thing is, in the Notification Drawer I get the ic_launcer icon
and in the Notification Area I get the trange "oo" icon you can see on the 
left side of the image below.

[picture of my Notification Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7wl1.png)

Have you every seen this? Do you know how to fix it? The phone on which 
I am testing is a Meizu U20, Android 6.

Comment: Problem is surely in Meizu Flyme OS. But some apps like Google Chrome, What'sApp, Telegram resolve this problem somehow.